# Set the iText 7 page size based on the HTML content

Tags: itext, itext7, html2pdf

I have the following Java program to create an iText PDF:

```
//Create the PDF file
public int CreatePDF(String[] pSrc, 
                     String pDest) 
           throws IOException 
{ 

    //Initialize
    ConverterProperties vProperties = new ConverterProperties();

    //Adding the fonts 
    FontProvider vfontProvider = new DefaultFontProvider(false, false, false);
    for (String font : FONTS) 
    {
        FontProgram vfontProgram = FontProgramFactory.createFont(font);
        vfontProvider.addFont(vfontProgram);
    }
    vProperties.setFontProvider(vfontProvider);

    PdfWriter vWriter = new PdfWriter(pDest, new WriterProperties().setCompressionLevel(9));
    PdfDocument vPDF = new PdfDocument(vWriter);
    PdfMerger vMerger = new PdfMerger(vPDF);

    //Convert to PDF
    for (String vHTML : pSrc)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream vArrByteAOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfDocument vDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(vArrByteAOS, new WriterProperties().setCompressionLevel(9)));
        vDoc.setDefaultPageSize(new PageSize(735, 1080));
        HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(vHTML, vDoc, vProperties);
        vDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(vArrByteAOS.toByteArray())));
        vMerger.merge(vDoc, 1, vDoc.getNumberOfPages());
        vDoc.close();
    }
    vPDF.close();
    return 0;
}
```

How can I set the Page Height (now hardcoded to 1080) based on the size of the HTML content (pSrc) in order to ensure that it fits to one page.

Comment: Please read the HTML to PDF tutorial, more specifically the section entitled **"Converting an HTML page to a single-page PDF"** of [chapter 4](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-4-creating-reports-using-pdfhtml).

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was helpful.

Comment: following  the link in the Bruno Lowagie comment i get a : Access denied
You are not authorized to access this page.

https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-4-creating-reports-using-pdfhtml

Comment: You have the link here https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/ebooks/itext-7-converting-html-to-pdf-with-pdfhtml/chapter-4-creating-reports-using-pdfhtml